# Mapping classic asp requests to .net in IIS6

Tags: asp.net, iis, asp-classic

Is it possible to map classic asp requests to ASP.NET in IIS6 by specifying a handler in web.config?

Or do we need to change the handler mapping directly in IIS?

Same question for IIS7.

Thanks
Ben

Comment: You mean that `page.asp` will actually hold ASP.NET code? Why not just call it `page.aspx`? Or do you mean run classic ASP via the .NET "engine"?

Comment: Is this done in order to preserve old links?

Answer (score 0):

You might be interested in the ASP Classic Compiler project which converts VBScript to ASP.NET compiled code:

http://aspclassiccompiler.codeplex.com/